# How to calculate $(a \cdot b\cdot c \cdot \ldots) \pmod{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

I need to calculate a basic equation $a \div b \pmod{c}$ where $a = x_1\cdot x_2 \cdot x_3 \cdot \ldots$ and similarly with $b$ where $c=10^9 + 7$.

So I was wondering if it can be split up:

$$a = ((x_1 \cdot x_2 \pmod{c})\cdot x_3)\pmod{c} \ldots$$

and just nest the modulus operators with each multiplication, I just am not sure if this is actually possible with the modulus operator.

Is it true that :

$$(x_1 \cdot x_2\cdot x_3)\pmod{c} \equiv ((x_1 \cdot x_2)\pmod{c} \cdot x_3)\pmod{c}$$ ?

Comment: Please use \pmod you'll find it formats better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this works because of the simple property :

> If $$a \equiv b \pmod{n}$$ and $$c \equiv d \pmod{n}$$ then $$ac \equiv bd \pmod{n}$$

From the definition of the modulo :

$$x_1 \cdot x_2 \equiv (x_1 \cdot x_2 \pmod{c} ) \pmod{c}$$ and obviously :

$$x_3 \equiv x_3 \pmod{c}$$

Now using the property :

$$x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot x_3 \equiv (x_1 \cdot x_2 \pmod{c} ) \cdot x_3 \pmod{c}$$

which is exactly what you wrote .

Basically you can reduce every number you want modulo $c$ in an expression and the expression will be unchanged modulo $c$ .

Comment: that is exactly what I wanted to hear thanks